# Select name from system table and select from this table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need dynamically obtain table name from system table and perform a select query on this table example:

`SELECT "schema"+'.'+"table" FROM  SVV_TABLE_INFO WHERE "table" LIKE '%blabla%'`

it returns `my_schema.the_main_blabla_table`

And after I get this table name I need to perform :

`SELECT * FROM my_schema.the_main_blabla_table LIMIT 100`

Is it possible to in a single query?

Comment: not a query. unless you query a function you prepare

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about select subquery after "from" i can say that you can do this.

You will get something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
  SELECT "schema"+'.'+"table" FROM  SVV_TABLE_INFO WHERE "table" LIKE '%blabla%'
)
LIMIT 100
```

Unfortunately, i can't test it on yor data, but i very interested in result because i have never done something like this. If i get your question incorrect, tell me pls.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but your code snippet works another way. The nested query returns a dataset, and outer select try to filter this dataset but doesn't perform a query on the returned table name. And the returned result is exactly what inner select returns, it can affect it only there are more than 100 rows :)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift does not support the ability to take the output of a query and use it as part of another query.

Your application will need to query Redshift to obtain the relevant table name(s), then make another call to Redshift to query that table.